# Name of the list operation that successively replaces a given element

Tags: list, naming

Does the list operation that successively replaces a given element of one list with each element of another (it arises in e.g. translating logic formulas to clause normal form) have a standard name?

Example: given inputs

```
[0, 1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]
```

And applying the operation at position 2, the output is

```
[[0, 1, a, 3],
 [0, 1, b, 3],
 [0, 1, c, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, this form of expansion

```
> 0 1 {a | b | c} 3 
0 1 a 3 
0 1 b 3 
0 1 c 3
```

is called *alternation*.